# Can I reload my React Native application using a command?

Tags: ios, debugging, react-native

I'm testing on a older iPhone and I have to shake the phone like a madman to get to the dev menu. Is there a command I can send through the bridge to reload or bring up the dev menu? I'm aware of live reload but that's not what I want.

For example on my Android device I can send `adb shell input keyevent 82` to simulate a shake event and bring up the dev menu.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to open dev menu without shaking phone. Here is the issue related to this problem: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/10191.

Nevertheless you can always try your code inside an iPhone emulator and open dev menu using `⌃⌘Z`.

Best regards.